Are Quantum States Coherent at Room Temperature, with no thermal isolation, if the timespan is very small?
I'm an EE, not a physicist, so please forgive if this question is dumb.
It is my understanding that coherent quantum states are shared by matter that forms a closed thermodynamic system.
Hypothetically, we could achieve this by cooling matter to absolute zero (which is of course impossible), because no information can be lost due to heat if there is no heat. The matter would need to be very dense, so that heat entering the system through its surface area is negligible. However, I googled if matter is heatless over a sufficiently small time horizon, and the answer is yes.
So I'm wondering:
Outside a lab, with no vacuum pumps, no cryogenic refrigeration, etc., does matter share a coherent quantum state over very short time spans?

Highly relevant and possibly a duplicate: Reason for decoherence time's dependence on variables?
